# How to make a GSheet fetch operation faster?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to load a row from my Google Sheet in my Flutter app that has about 100,000 cells. My operation takes about 10 seconds to fetch the row using the v4 api, can anyone tell me is there a way to make the read operation faster?

Here's my code:

```
 FutureBuilder(
  future: UserManager().getById('12949233'),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
   if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    if (snapshot.data != null) {
       return tasks(snapshot.data);
      } else {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
       }
        } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
       }
       })
```

Here's my `Future`,

```
//This returns a Map that contains my entire row by the specific id
    Future<Data> getById(String id) async {
        await init();
        final map = await _dataSheet.values.map.rowByKey(
          id,
          fromColumn: 1,
        );
        return map == null ? null : Data.fromGsheets(map);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please note:** The catch here is, if you are getting your result delayed in your `Debug Mode`, then I must tell you that, the app will perform faster in your `Release Mode`. Simply check the app using the below command and see if the result persists or has some changes

```
flutter run --release
```